# How do I get `sort` and `bool => should` query to work in tandem?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following query for fetching all products. What I'm trying to achieve is keep the out of stock products I.E. products with `stock_sum` = `0` at the bottom:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "updated_at": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "stock_sum": {
              "gte": 1,
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But with the above query `sort` seems to completely override `should`, which is how it's suppose to behave I guess. A couple of things that I tried are changing the `should` to `must` in this case the **out of stock** products, are left out completely (that's not what I want, I still want the out of stock products at the bottom).

Another approach is remove **sort**, and then the should query seems to have an effect, but again I need the sort. So my question is how do I get `sort` and `bool => should` query to work in tandem ? I.E. sort by `updated_at` but also keep the `stock_sum = 0` at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `match_all` and `constant_score` query in the same `should` clause and sorting first by `_score` by `asc`, then by `updated_at` by `desc` should work for your example. Here is an example query:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "updated_at": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
             "filter": {
              "term": {
                "stock_sum": 0
              }
            },
            "boost": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks is there anyway i can see the `_score` ? i does't seem to appear in elasticview

Comment: I don't know what elasticview is. But if you send a post request to {ip}:{port}/{indexName}/_search with the query above, you can see scores. Or you can use kibana's dev tools to query your index at elasticsearch.

Comment: thanks that works !! one more question if i add `"boost": 10` below `stock_sum: 0` , it seems to have the same effect. is there a major difference though ?

Comment: It should work the same for your case. For your case, you can remove constant score, and add boost directly to term query. If you are going to use single term query it will work. When you have multiple conditions, for examples, stock=0 and price > 10, you use bool>must or bool>should for filtering and wrap with a constant score query to give them a constant score, instead of summing all of their scores.